# Path to temporary Wicked PDF file in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I am creating a PDF file using Wicked:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>')
```

I assume that this creates a temporary file somewhere. How can I get the path to this temp file?

Comment: The wicked_pdf gem doesn't appear to expose the `Tempfile` at all.  Would be useful though.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this when you are creating the pdf only u can pass in the option of your desired temp path

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string('<h1>Hello There!</h1>', {temp_path: "your path here")
```

[Refer this link for more inputs this contains the function that you are using and the inputs that can be passed](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/63803cbb30a9e122e63b8487c692dc8e5a1e4a66/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L54)

Comment: `temp_path` actually expect a folder directory, rather than a file path. Please check https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf/tempfile.rb

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to example of https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#super-advanced-usage.

The official example use `File`

```rb
pdf = render_to_string pdf: "some_file_name", template: "templates/pdf", encoding: "UTF-8"

# then save to a file
save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

You may use `tempfile` to do it as

```
pdf_string = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(...)

overlay = Tempfile.new('overlay')
overlay.binmode
overlay.write(pdf_string)
overlay.close
overlay.path # to get path
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [source](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/d96abcb6df4c137525d27626b9cc2d5319516ade/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L52) of WickedPDF it has a [TempFile](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/d96abcb6df4c137525d27626b9cc2d5319516ade/lib/wicked_pdf/tempfile.rb#L3)

The temporary file should be created in the temporary directory as defined in `options`, or in `Dir.tmpdir`.

Comment: The temp file looks something like this: /var/folders/5d/rk6vftfs7h52jxx2gxf35mjh0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20180104-12707-151pvdz.pdf. I got this from the log. But I wonder how to retrieve this fpath + file after creating the PDF.